# Best way to make both a compile-time and runtime version of a function

Tags: c++, templates, runtime, compile-time

I have a function that will be called by both compile-time and runtime functions (`gtest` and python `ctypes`). I need a templated version and one with the templated variables as function parameters. For example

```
template<int A, int B, int C>
void function_compiletime(int a, int b, int c) {
    // code section 1
}

void function_runtime(int a, int b, int c, int A, int B, int C) {
    // code section 2
}
```

Where `// code section 1` is identical to `// code section 2`. I am cautious that I might accidentally alter something in `// code section 1` and not in `// code section 2`. How can enforce that the body of the functions should be identical?

Comment: Have the first function call the second one, with all six parameters, and do absolutely nothing else?

Comment: First function is not executed at compile time, it only has a few compile time parameters.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik losing compile time optimizations

Comment: I would just make the whole thing one inline function, and trust the compiler to optimize things. I default to relying on the compiler to optimize the code for me if I give it all the info it needs to do that, and then attempt to force-feed optimized code like that only if I'm proven wrong.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The code section is highly optimized SIMD functions. I want the compiler to take advantage of any aggressive optimizations it can make.

Comment: I would say that the actual approach here will depend entirely on the actual code, and the compiler's behavior. Have you actually checked that, that if it's just one inline function the compiler doesn't optimize it the way you want to, so all of this is just much ado over nothing? gcc even has an explicit attribute that says: inline this function, or I'll feed you to my bitchipper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Best way to make both a compile-time and runtime version of a function
>
> How can enforce that the body of the functions should be identical?

By defining a single constexpr function:

```
constexpr void
function_runtime(int a, int b, int c, int A, int B, int C)
{
    // code section
}
```

Comment: Can this function do anything useful at compile time, considering it takes in no references and returns no value?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Probably not. I suspect this is a case of over-simplified example.